# Type mismatch on java and cannot instantiate the type of object

Tags: java, interface

right now i'm learning about interface in Java and now i got confused when this error is pop out

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Bola to bangunRuang
- Cannot instantiate the type Bola

and the code is

```
package Modul5no2;

public interface bangunRuang {

public double keliling();

public double luas();

public double volume();
}  *//this is the interface*

public class kotakBalok implements bangunRuang {
double keliling,luas,volume;
public double keliling(double p, double l, double t){
    keliling = 4*(p+l+t);
    return keliling;
}

public double luas(double p,double l, double t){
    luas = 2*((p*l)+(p*t)*(l*t));
    return luas;
}

public double volume(double p,double l, double t){
    volume = p*l*t;
    return volume;
}

} *//this is for collect from interface*


public class Driver {
public static void main(String[]args){

    bangunRuang br1 = new Bola();  //i assume this is the problem

    br1.keliling();
    br1.luas();
    br1.volume();
}
}
```

ok thank u for your attention
hope you understand what i mean lol xD

Comment: where is the class Bola ?

Comment: We don't see any definition for Bola. It ought to be something like a `class Bola implements bangunRuang`.

Comment: Please show all your code that is relevant.

Comment: why do you think this should work? bangunRuang br1 = new Bola();

Comment: maybe you meant `bangunRuang br1 = new kotakBalok ();` ?

Comment: This shouldn't be a question on SO, you should figure this out by yourself if your goal is to learn about interfaces.

Comment: sorry guys i just realize i'm not careful when see the error, now the problem is solved! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually not clear what you want to achieve here.

Didn't you get compilation error in class `kotakBalok` because you have not provided body or implemented the methods of the interface `bangunRuang` as your class `class kotakBalok implements bangunRuang` .
Though you have methods with same name but have different signature than the methods of interface , So that doesn't count as providing implementation of methods of interface.

In your `Driver` class you are calling new on class Bola i.e `bangunRuang br1 = new Bola()` but you in the code you provided the class Bola does not exist. perhaps you want to do `bangunRuang br1 = new kotakBalok();`

At last this will not work if you have not provided the implementation of methods of interface `bangunRuang` in class `kotakBalok`